# Selenium CSS locator space in locator

Tags: selenium

I know that selenium can use css locators.

I know that the syntax is something like this:

xpath=//div[@id,'topLeft')//span[contains(@class,'name')]
or 
css=#topLeft .name

Now, what if .name is like this: //span[contains(@class,'name with space')]

Then it would fail... HOw to look for a locator that has space in it?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Solution:  css=span.name.with.space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class names can't have spaces. However, you can define **multiple** classes for a single element by putting a space between them. Take a look at the [id and class identifiers section in the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) for more.

You should be able to use the CSS locator by using only one of the classes.

If that doesn't work, double check your CSS selector using a tool like [Firefinder for FireBug](http://robertnyman.com/firefinder/). I was able use Selenium-IDE with an element that had two classes. For the HTML

```
<div class="c1 c2">
    <span class"s1">Test</span>
</div>
```

I used the selector

```
css=div.c1 span
```

Comment: Yeah. Say that to the devs at my company who have class names like this: button AddComment IntegrationButton.

Comment: I'm not saying there can't be spaces. I'm pointing out that those aren't all one class. Those are individual classes. If you're trying to identify one with a selector, just pick a class.

Comment: Now i'm the one who is dumb... I never thought that an element can have multiple classes? Damn... I learn something new everyday. :) That means if i see a class name like this: "button Something submitter"... That that element has button class Something class and submitter class? 

And if i search for button class then this one will also be found?

Comment: But what if there are more c1 and c2 around alone but only one element with booth classes? And i need THAT element?

Comment: I can simply use + to add class names. Thanks. :)

Comment: That is NOT true... Adding classes to selectors is with DOT notation. Like:
css=div#ClassName a.button.major.moreClassname

Answer (score -2):

With CSS its easier than using a long xpath:

span.class1.class2